# Can an XPC service link against the framework that embeds it?

Tags: xcode, xpc, xcode10

I am writing a framework that accepts plug-ins to implement some operations. Since these plug-ins are less trusted than first-party code, I would like to host them in an XPC service, which I can make extremely unprivileged and can prevent from causing much harm to the system.

The plug-ins, however, should have access to essentially the same API as first-party code that runs in-process. For the sake of simplicity, I would like the XPC process to link against the framework itself.

The problem, of course, is that the framework embeds the XPC process, and the XPC process links against the framework. Xcode considers this a cyclic dependency and refuses to build in this configuration. This is true even if the "Copy only when installing" checkbox is checked.

Since the XPC service is not needed at link time, this is arguably artificial: it would be possible to build the framework binary, then the XPC service, and last copy the service to the framework.

Is there a way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, invert the build relationship. Make the XPC service copy itself into the framework. You may also need to resign the framework.

Delete the dependency relationship between the XPC Service and the Framework target and remove the "Copy XPC Services" step.

Add a Run Script phase to the framework target that creates a "Versions/A/XPCServices" folder (and the symlink at the root of your .framework), but otherwise does nothing else.

On the XPC Service target link the framework. This creates a target dependency relationship which is fine. Add a Run Script phase. Have the script copy the `.xpc` bundle from `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)` into the correct location. Something like `rsync -av ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}/ ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/MyFramework.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}/`